# How do i specify the axis range in React-Vis

Tags: d3.js, react-vis

How do i specify the axis range in React-Vis

For Ex: 
0 to 100 for Y Axis and the data is as below

data={[ {x: 1, y: 45}, {x: 2, y: 50}, {x: 3, y: 85} ]}/>

**The YAxis must range 0 to 100 even though the max Y value here is 85**

Answer (score 6):

Use the xDomain or yDomain props on the XYPlot component `<XYPlot xDomain={[0, 50]}`

Answer (score 1):

From their docs about scales at:
https://uber.github.io/react-vis/documentation/general-principles/scales-and-data

"To redefine a scale, you must pass a prop to the series that uses that scale. The prop names are based on the name of the attribute: name + Domain, name + Range, name + Type, name + Padding (for instance: yDomain, colorType, xRange)."

So for your purpose, you would set `<XYPlot yDomain=[0,100]></XYPlot>`